# Consumir Web Service PHP

Tags: php, web-service, soap

Estou tentando fazer o consumo de um *Web Service* e não estou conseguindo obter os resultados esperados.

Aparentemente o erro pelo que pude perceber está na estrutura como estou passando o *Vetor* de argumentos para chamada do método, já tentei fazer de diversas maneiras e ainda continuo com o erro.

A estrutura de requisição do web service que estou usando é esta apresentada abaixo.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.senior.com.br">
      <soapenv:Body>
        <ser:ColaboradoresAdmitidos>
          <user>String</user>
          <password>String</password>
          <encryption>Integer</encryption>
          <parameters>
            <NumEmp>Integer</NumEmp>
            <AbrTipCol>String</AbrTipCol>
            <IniPer>DateTime</IniPer>
            <FimPer>DateTime</FimPer>
          </parameters>
        </ser:ColaboradoresAdmitidos>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

O Meu código PHP é este:

```
$url = new SoapClient('http://10.50.3.3:8080/g5-senior-services/rubi_Synccom_senior_g5_rh_fp_colaboradoresAdmitidos?wsdl');

    $funcao     = 'ColaboradoresAdmitidos';
    $argumentos = array('ColaboradoresAdmitidos'=> 
                          array('user'        => 'USER',
                                'password'    => 'XXX',
                                'encryption'  =>  0,
                                'parameters'  => 
                                array('NumEmp'=> 1,

                                      'AbrTipCol' => 1,

                                      'IniPer'    => '01/01/2018',

                                      'FimPer'    => '01/01/2018')
                           ) 
                  );

$opcoes  = array('location' => 'http://10.50.3.3:8080/g5-senior-services/rubi_Synccom_senior_g5_rh_fp_colaboradoresAdmitidos');
$result  = $url->__soapCall($funcao,$argumentos,$opcoes);
```

O resultado que obtenho é o seguinte: 
Ocorreu um erro ao executar o serviço "AP - Colaboradores admitidos": Valores de parâmetros obrigatórios não foram informados.

Detalhes:Parâmetros obrigatórios não informados:

- NumEmp
- AbrTipCol
- IniPer

Detalhe que estou passando os parâmetros que a mensagem diz que não passei, se alguém puder me ajudar, talvez eu esteja errando apenas na montagem do *array* de argumentos para a chamada do método `soap__call`